# In Angular 2, is it possible to insert a custom component in an other component?

Tags: angular, components

I'm wondering if it's possible with Angular 2 to create custom components in a library and used it in the `app.component.ts` like this:

```
app.component.ts
----------------
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template:`<comp-a>
                <comp-b></comp-b>
                <comp-b></comp-b>
                <comp-b></comp-b>
               </comp-a>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer ! With Angular 2, you can use the `<ng-content>` element.

```
compA.component.ts
----------------
@Component({
    selector: 'comp-a', 
    template:`<div>
                <ng-content></ng-content>
               </div>'

app.component.ts
----------------
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app', 
    template:`<comp-a>
                <comp-b></comp-b>
                <comp-b></comp-b>
                <comp-b></comp-b>
               </comp-a>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it's possible.just write a new component use that component in where you want view place it wondering in that place

Example:-

**file1:-**

```
@Component({

    selector: 'custom-component',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'custom.html'
})

export class LeavesComponent { }
```

**file2:-**

```
@Component({

    selector: 'custom-component',
    moduleId: module.id,
    template: `<div> 
                   <custom-component></custom-component>
                    //you can add more files same like
               </div>`
})

export class ParentComponent { }
```

Comment: I know it's possible to create nested component. It's not my question. In your example,if I understood, <custom-component-2> is inside <custom-component-1> direclty in the template property. In my case, I would like to use 2 components in a main file and the first one wrap the other one without using an attribute tag like <custom-component content="customComponent2"></custom-component>.